# Extract data frame column after pipe, in base R

Tags: r

I'd like to use the `[[` base R function to extract a column from a dataframe at the end of a sequence of piped operations. But I get an error message that doesn't make sense to me. Here's a simple example of the error message:

```
> mtcars |> `[[`("mpg")
Error: function '[[' not supported in RHS call of a pipe
```

This example is meant to accomplish the same result as the following:

```
mtcars[['mpg']]
```

Why doesn't the simple example `` mtcars |> `[[`("mpg") `` work? What can I do instead, using just base R?

Comment: You're right. My question is a duplicate which I will flag as such.

Comment: Of interest, dplyr `%>%` allows you to reference the [[ function in a manner that `|>` will not.  (e.g. `mtcars %>% [[(.,'mpg')` --with of course the backticks around the [[.

Comment: Yep, that's why I posed the question. I was frustrated that the base R pipe wouldn't let me do something that the magrittr/dplyr pipe is very commonly used for. Appreciate you bringing this up.

Comment: `mtcars |> (\`[[\`)("mpg")` or `mtcars |> base::\`[[\`("mpg")` will work.